# SQL Cursor outputs "procedure successfully completed" instead of a set message

Tags: sql, oracle, cursor

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE check_reviewer (vc_username VARCHAR2, vc_password VARCHAR2) IS
    CURSOR cur_reviewer IS
    SELECT username, password, reviewer_id
    FROM reviewers
    WHERE username = vc_username AND password = vc_password;
    vn_reviews NUMBER;
BEGIN 
    FOR rec_cur_reviewer IN cur_reviewer LOOP
        IF rec_cur_reviewer.username = vc_username
            AND rec_cur_reviewer.password = vc_password
        THEN
            vn_reviews := func_reviews_from_reviewers(rec_cur_reviewer.reviewer_id);
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Amount of reviews for reviewer ' || rec_cur_reviewer.reviewer_id || ' is: ' ||vn_reviews);
        ELSE 
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NO REVIEWS');
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
EXCEPTION 
    WHEN OTHERS THEN 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM);
END check_reviewer;
/
```

It outputs "procedure successfully completed" instead of the DBMS messages. I've tried set serveroutput on already to no avail.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: I think oracle sql, I downloaded it from their site

Comment: If there's no matching data, the loop won't ever get into the IF statement, and won't get to the NO REVIEWS line.